# New files not being compressed in a compressed folder in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, ntfs, file-management, compression

After marking folder as compressed in Windows 10, new files are not being compressed.

Steps:

- create a folder on your desktop and then right click -> properties -> advanced -> enable "Compress contents to save disk space"
- enter the folder -> right click -> new text document, name it whatever you want and press enter key
- the file will be compressed as expected, with a name presented in blue
- open Chrome or Edge web browser and find a webpage with any image
- right click on image and select "Save image as" into this folder
- the image won't be compressed

What to do to change this weird behaviour?

P.S. I know JPEG is already compressed, but this was just an example to get a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens if you save your file using Chrome or Edge, but it works fine if you use Firefox or Internet Explorer.

If you need it to work in Chrome, try filing a bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).